# Stream Sound from Ubuntu to Android

Tags: usb, audio, linux, streaming

I got tired of replugging my headset between a desktop and Android when someone calls me. Is there a way to stream sound from Ubuntu (I use [Pulseaudio](http://pulseaudio.org/)) to Android phone over wifi or usb?

Comment: i found this but not sure how to make it work together http://www.damonkohler.com/2009/01/rhythmbox-shout2send-plugin.html

Comment: and there is a way to use vlc http://traveldevel.com/ but it gives an error "too many errors" when i try to stream over http. there is also this one which i will try later http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/related/d0hr0/howto_live_streaming_videoaudio_from_vlc_to_your/

Comment: I'd get a bluetooth dongle and send phone audio to your pc (in a snap) :)

Comment: There's a very similar question on superuser, with multiple answers:

https://superuser.com/questions/605445/how-to-stream-my-gnu-linux-audio-output-to-android-devices-over-wi-fi

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu has built [Ubuntu One Mobile](https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/) for that very purpose. The service is free to try for one month, then $3.99/month (or $39.99 yearly). It's worth mentioning that the paid account gives you 25GB of storage and unlimited streaming for devices running Android 2.1+, iOS 3.1+ as well as Windows XP, Vista and 7 (and there are rates for additional storage).

(*For those who do not wish to stream music, Ubuntu One provides 5GB of cloud storage for free.)*

Comment: ubuntu one is no more...

Answer (score 6):

Yes! There is an app called Remote Audio which tunnels your computer's audio output over either SSH or 1 or 2 other protocols. I just installed it and haven't set it up yet, but I plan on using it alongside a remote VNC connection to my desktop at home so I can use Energy XT remotely to sequence song ideas from wherever in the world I happen to be. =)

I'm sure the Ubuntu thing works awesome for music, and probably involves a simpler set-up, but this will stream ANY sound your computer makes, and it's free (and works with any *nix system). The Rhythembox thing you posted about would work awesome too, but you need to set up an Icecast media streaming server first.

Comment: Do you have a link for the app? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

I use the old Winamp [Shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/download) streaming server tools. Then use one of the apps that play Shoutcast stations. Winamp (official app, but Shoutcast streaming still in development as of 11/8/2010) or [XiiaLive](http://www.xiialive.com/) ([AppBrain link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/xiialive-lite-online-radio/com.android.DroidLiveLite)).

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of an UPnP AV approach? The protocol allows streaming of media between various devices in the same network (e.g. Wifi). [There is a large variety of servers and clients for all the OSes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients).

For example, [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) is a well-known media server also available for Ubuntu. For playback on the phone you could use allShare, which comes preinstalled on some phones, or a free client like [BubbleUPNP](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp) or [Skifta](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skifta.android.app).

Comment: +1 MediaTomb also streams video's to you Android device.

Answer (score 2):

You can install airbubble on your android, which works as a speaker using apple's AirPlay (DAAP) protocol.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.airbubble

Pulseaudio can be configured to stream to any AirPlay receiver - check this answer for details on setting that up:
https://superuser.com/questions/331126/how-can-you-stream-music-from-ubuntu-to-airplay-speakers-on-your-network-with-ub

With airbubble running, it should show up as a speaker option in the ubuntu sound menu.

Comment: nope airbubble is not showing up

Answer (score 1):

Check out subsonic. www.subsonic.org
It has its own app in the market and should play nice with phone calls. 
Takes about 2 seconds to setup on an internal only network and 3 min to access it from anywhere.