# shoutcast not working in android 2.2 - not even in latest winamp

Tags: streaming, shoutcast

I have spent for 30 hours searching for a solution,  however, I need help.  I want to provide live stream on an android phone with a user having to download an app.

I have used shoutcast but that does not help and when i go to m.mysite.com and click play from android browser it gives unsupported format.

however, this site:  http://stream.radiojavan.com/radiojavan if I go to it, and then from android browser it plays the stream.

Any help will be a great help.

Comment: Hi, 

Sorry for the confusion. User will download my app where there will be link which will open the shoutcast stream in a browser. Now, when the stream is opened, it gives an unsupported media type error.

Regarding the audio stream, it is an MP3 Stream so i think it should work. I will still verify this again to see that switching works fine or not?

For winamp, http://stream.radiojavan.com/radiojavan was working in winamp so you have any idea why my stream (http://core.crystalone.net:9000/listen.pls) is not running?

Comment: If this is a development question (it's a little difficult to tell) then you should direct it to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) as it would be considered off-topic here even if it pertains to Android development.

Comment: This is not a development question so i will like to stick to this site. Also in my pc i did not see "Add comment" option for the yday question so i needed to submit new answer, however, i will take care of this in future.

Comment: You should add this information to your original question. You can always edit your own question to improve it (add clarity, provide further details, fix errors, etc.)

Comment: Android supports RTSP streams, is your stream RTSP?

Answer (score 1):

What phone and Android version have you got? The description for WinAmp in the Market says that Shoutcast support in WinAmp is only available for phones running Android 2.2 or above.

This previous question [Stream Sound from Ubuntu to Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2610/stream-sound-from-ubuntu-to-android) has an answer that says that [XiiaLive](http://www.appbrain.com/app/xiialive-lite-online-radio/com.android.DroidLiveLite) ([official site](http://www.xiialive.com/)) should support Shoutcast.

Comment: I have Motorola, android 2.2, and latest winamp (downloaded yesterday only). Also xiialive is an app and so as winamp. If things does not work in winamp then i think it will not work here too.

Is it problem with shout cast stream, it has version 1.9 so may be that is an issue?

Comment: @Jeff So you don't want to use an app? Your question specifically says that you do, I'm confused? Xiaalive is a totally different app from WinAmp, just because something doesn't work in one, doesn't always mean it won't work in the other. Sorry I've got no idea about Shoutcast server versions, but I think there are two audio stream formats you can use, MP3 or HE-AAC, have you checked which you're  using, and tried switching the stream to the other?